# PHP DOMDocument "Creating default object from empty value"

Tags: php, object, default, domdocument

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName($key)->item(0)->nodeValue = (string) $value;
```

I have this line which throws this error. I am working with DOMDocument for years and never experienced this before. Actually I am testing the $dom before just to make sure it's all good like this:

```
if (gettype($dom) === "object") {
    if ($dom instanceof DOMDocument) {
```

Comment: Is `$dom->getElementsByTagName($key)->length>0`?

Comment: The problem is solved. The $dom was an outdated version from memcached, which just needed to be read again from the file. My bad.